# Problem with update project in Laravel from 5.8 to 6

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-6

I have project in Laravel 5.8. I want update it to 6.0. How can I update my project to version 6?

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.26",
        "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~4.0",
        "evilnet/dotpay": "^2.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.4",
        "geocoder-php/nominatim-provider": "^5.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.7",
        "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "^2.6",
        "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "^4.1",
        "torann/laravel-meta-tags": "^3.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": {
        "packagist.org": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/psCMS/Functions/image_thumb_function.php",
            "app/psCMS/Functions/set_correct_image_orientation.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have error when I run: composer update

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove evilnet/dotpay 2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Installation request for evilnet/dotpay ^2.1 -> satisfiable by evilnet/dotpay[2.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - evilnet/dotpay 2.1.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.8.35].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3].
```

How can I repair it?
Is posible do it in my project?

My file Composer.json is correct? Is posible update?

Please help me.

Comment: There is a guide how to migrate from laravel 5.8 to 6.x from Laravel website: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repository [`evilnet/dotpay`](https://github.com/axotion/laravel-dotpay/) only supports Laravel 5.x versions. So you will never be able to update to Laravel 6

There are only three possible ways:

1. Open an issue in GitHub and ask to upgrade the package in order to support Laravel 6.x version
2. Use another package.
3. Check the API documentation for that service (I think it's a Polish service right?) and write your own Guzzle wrapper getting inspiration from the source code of dotpay repository